# nopCommerce https ssl

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, https, webforms

I have a question to ask , I am using nopCommerce v1.6 and I see that in administration section it is using ssl and https protocol. So I want to ask,, how it is possible to use https and ssl without access to iis to specify certificate ? thank you

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly, you would like to see the admin section of the NopCommerce without accessing the IIS. You would have to modify the BaseNopController located in Nop.Admin.Controllers.

There is an attribute as below.

```
[NopHttpsRequirement(SslRequirement.Yes)]
public class BaseNopController : Controller
```

Change value SslRequirement to No and then NopService admin section will not require ssl. 
In case if your concern was not having SSL self-signed certificate, you could use self certify feature of the IIS server. Check this [ScottGu's](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/06/tip-trick-enabling-ssl-on-iis7-using-self-signed-certificates.aspx) post for more details.